# Windows Server 2008 R2 NTP ignoring SpecialPollInterval

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, ntp

I've pointed the 2k8 machine to the NTP server and it updates fine on the original bootup.  But I want it to update every 30 seconds.  It's for a practical and I have to show NTP in action.  It keeps defaulting to 900 seconds, even after I've put "0x1" at the end of the NTP Server IP and set the specificpollinterval to 30.

This method words in XP just fine..but for some reason 2k8 seems to be ignoring this registry value.

Any ideas?

Comment: You say Specificpollinginterval, do you mean Special?  This is the regkey to change: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\TimeProviders\ NtpClient\SpecialPollInterval

Comment: Yes I meant Special*.  That is the registry key I changed and it still defaults to 900.

Comment: Is the server part of a domain?  Is it a domain controller?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken the minimum poll interval is 64 seconds.  If you go anywhere below that number it defaults back to the recommended setting of 900 seconds.

Comment: Turns out my DNS records were messed up and it wasn't able to find the NTP server.  Fixed that and now it's working properly.  thanks for the help